# TP4056 LiPo charger output voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, lipo

For a project I'm looking for a charging solution to charge a LiPo battery, while at the same time being able to power a microcontroller with 3.3 V.

For that purpose, I bought a few TP4056 boards that also include a DW01A and a FS8205A and should be able to provide charging and protection.

The schematic of this circuit is:

[image]

I've been experimenting with these 2 batteries:

[image]

One is a 3.7 V, 1200 mAh battery, the other is a CN18650 9800 mAh battery (or at least, that's what is printed on them).

Charging them seems to work fine, after a while the green LED on the TP4056 lights up, indicating that charging is done.

At full charge, both batteries give just over 4 V. Since my microcontroller requires 3.3v, I used a XC6203P332PR ([datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/87197/TOREX/XC6203P332PR.html)) to regulate the voltage. I hooked the Vin up to the OUT+ of the TP4056 circuit, Vss (ground) to OUT-.

I expected OUT+ and OUT- to give the same voltage as the B+ and B-, but unfortunately, it doesn't. With the 1200 mAh, I only get about 0.7 V on OUT+ and OUT-, with the 9800 mAh, I see erratic behavior, sometimes it gives the proper output voltage, but a lot of times, I only get 0.7 V out of it.

I can't quite figure out what's going wrong. I've tried multiple TP4056 boards and multiple batteries, but did not get a consistent figure. Googling around, I find mixed information about the TP4056, apparently there are also cloned versions of this chip around.

I was wondering if anyone knows the cause of my problem, am I doing something obviously wrong, or is the TP4056 just not the right way to go? And if not, are there any other suitable (and preferably affordable) solutions around?

Comment: I'm having similar problems with my cheap Aliexpress TP4056 board: looks like the DW01A's overvoltage and/or overcurrent detector is (incorrectly) triggering, which disconnects the battery.  I found that momentarily shorting the B- and OUT- pins causes the part to work (by lowering the battery voltage once the load is connected or reducing the initial current the part senses).
I'm trying to figure out a decent circuit fix, but haven't so far.  I could add a momentary switch "start" button, but I'd like to avoid that and just have the board operate as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Desolder any of the output pins from the TP4056 module to the regulator and then solder it back. The voltage will return.

I am using this module with a boost convertor in my RC transmitter as a 10v battery and this situation happens time to time. I have no idea why though.